# Use processing-instruction in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to use processing-instruction in XSLT.

Logic: If there is `<?Table Sideturn?>` it should add `<context:sideturn>`

Input:

```
<table-wrap id="tab_A.1" position="anchor">
  <?Table Sideturn?>
  <label>Table A.1</label>
  <caption/>
  <table>
    <tbody/>
  </table>
</table-wrap
```

Output should be:

```
<context:sideturn>
  <table/>
</context:sideturn>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('Table Sideturn')">
         <context:sideturn>
            <table/>
         </context:sideturn>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <context:not-sideturn>
            <table/>
         </context:not-sideturn>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Above my xpath is not working well. How can I resolve this? I am using XSLT 2.0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing instruction

```
<?Table Sideturn?>
```

Has a name of `Table` and a value of `Sideturn`. So you need to check for it based on its name and value:

```
<xsl:when
  test="preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('Table')[normalize-space() = 'Sideturn']">
```

As noted in the comments, I'm using `normalize-space()` here since some processors may treat the value as having a space at the beginning.

Comment: It's probably also a good idea to use normalize-space() on the value. IIRC, there are differences between processors as to whether whitespace in the value is stripped.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks, will add that.

Answer (score 1):

**You Can try this:**

```
<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('Table Sideturn')">
```

Instead-of

```
<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('Table')">
```

Becouse Space is not allowed in element name.